# How to convert Characters to Int in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift4

I have `readLine()` which gives me the character. So, I have this:

`223 345 567` and so on. So, when I convert them to Int first thing says these are character so, I researched and found this solution and when I use this:

```
let size    = readLine()
var array   = [Int]()
let numbers = readLine()

for number in numbers!
{
  if let integer = Int(String(number))
  {
      array.append(integer)
  }
}
print(array)
```

So, when I am printing the array, I am getting these as `[2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7]` instead of `[223,345,567]`. Can anyone help?

Here is the extract of new code.

```
let numbers = readLine()
var array   = [Int]()
guard let numberStrings = numbers?.components(separatedBy: " ") else{
fatalError()
}
for number in numberStrings {
if let validNumber = Int(number) {
    array.append(validNumber)
}
}

print(array)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for number in numbers!
```

This line of code extracts each `character` in the `string` `(223 345 567)` and tries to convert it to `int`. That's why it converts each valid number in string and left the spaces.
You need to first split the `string` in to `array` of `string` numbers then iterate through the array to convert them.

Split it, further iterate through `strNumArray` and convert them to `integers`

```
var array   = [Int]()
if let strNumArray = numbers?.components(separatedBy: " ") {
    for number in strNumArray {
        if let integer = Int(String(number)) {
            array.append(integer)
        }
    }
}
print(array)
```

> And in more swifty way

```
var arrayInt = numbers.split(separator: " ").map{Int($0)}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: value of type 'String?' has no member 'components' let strNumArray as the numbers = readLine() is giving me String. What to do about it?

Comment: if 'numbers' is optional use if let or guard

Comment: @Rob13 adding guard or if let helped you ?

Comment: Nope, same error. I just tried this more swifty way and it works. Why didn't it worked with the above code? I am using Swift 4.1, is that the issue?

Comment: I had updated the answer yesterday. Please see if this works for you.

Comment: @Rob13 also if possible share screenshot of the code and error you are getting.

Comment: Please check the above comment ^

Comment: No swift 4.1 should not be the issue. Can I have extract of the latest code that you have ?
Also using more swifty way is better, but still other one should also be working.

Comment: Added the extract in the question above.

Comment: I think that one is working piece of code. Share the code that is not working

Comment: I have just check on xcode with swift 4.1 this piece of code have no error. Please share screen shot of the error you are getting.

Comment: Also use the code I have in answer above swifty way if you want to avoid fatalError() function call in case of no value in optional 'numbers'

Comment: In the above answer, you can see that the size is getting input. So, like suppose if I have a condition and I do not want to receive input after it fails, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to **split** the string and find every number string and then convert them to `Int`.

```
let numbers = readLine()
var numberArray: [Int] = []
guard let numberStrings = numbers?.components(separatedBy: " ") else {
    fatalError()
}

for number in numberStrings {
    if let validNumber = Int(number) {
        numberArray.append(validNumber)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this `error: value of type 'String?' has no member 'components' let strNumArray ` as the `numbers = readLine() is giving me String`. What to do about it?

Comment: Still same error. `error: value of type 'String' has no member 'components' `

Comment: @Rob13 can you share a screenshot of your xcode showing that error along with the code?